# Use personalised information in a custom google actio

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, google-account, google-assist-api

I’ve built a google action that talks to my bespoke web Api.

The actions code currently has personal details hard coded into it.  I need to make it so that when someone uses it for the first time it asks them for a username password and URL.

Is there a way to do this?  Or maybe there is a way for a user to add those details to there google account in some way that the action can read them.

Alternatively is there a way to publish an action so only specific users can access it?

Answer (score 1):

In general, asking for a username and password is a bad approach for Actions, for several reasons, and asking for a URL can be quite a mess. Particularly if you're expecting the user to access the Action via voice or a device that doesn't support a keyboard.

The better approach is to use [Account Linking](https://developers.google.com/assistant/identity) to connect their Google Account to an account they have created on your system. If you need additional one-time configuration information, you can have them provide this information for their account via a webapp, store it in a datastore of some sort, and then access it when they contact your webhook via the Action.

There is no way to have the Assistant enforce access to a production Action. You can [publish](https://developers.google.com/assistant/console/releases) an Alpha release to up to 20 accounts, but this is still treated as a "test" version.